# ¿Por qué no funciona el operador -- en una función recursiva?

Tags: c++, funciones

Aquí una función recursiva que tengo:

```
int factorial(int n){
    if(n == 0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return n * factorial(n--);
    }
}
```

Pienso que debería de funcionar, ya que `--` corresponde a `-=` si no me equivoco...

Comment: El post-operador funciona luego de usado el valor. O sea, primero se calcula la expresión en la que aparece, luego se decrementa. Tienes que usar '--n' para decrementar antes de calcular.

Comment: Mm eso ya lo sabía, ¡Pero se me había olvidado desde un tiempo! De todas formas no me funciona, ya que cuando la llamo se imprime 0 (Sé que lo correcto sería usar -1, pero es que tengo esa duda).

Answer (score 3):

```
int factorial(int n){
    if(n == 0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return n * factorial(--n);
    }
}
```

Según la lógica usar el pre incremento `--n` efectivamente debería funcionar. Pero no es el caso del lenguaje C++. El problema radica en que no hay un orden específico para la evaluación de las variables en la expresión.  En lenguajes como Java, C# ese código funciona sin problemas ya que la evaluación está definida de izquierda a derecha.